# Corrupted netcdf output file related with chunk size or dimension naming

Tags: hdf5, netcdf

I noticed, that in the following program the created `netcdf` file is corrupted, i.e., executing `ncdump -h out.nc` produces errors.

```
#include <netcdf>

/**
 * This file produces a corrupted nc output file.
 * Compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp -lnetcdf -lnetcdf_c++4 
 */

// this is the first non-working 
// chunk size. It does work with 1048576
// 1048576 is representable by exactly 20 bits.
#define CHUNK_SIZE 1048577

using namespace std;
using namespace netCDF;
using namespace netCDF::exceptions;

int main() 
{
    typedef std::vector<size_t> vs;
    typedef std::vector<netCDF::NcDim> vd;

    try
    {
        NcFile outFile = NcFile("out.nc", NcFile::replace);

        // create the dimensions complying to the AMBER specs
        NcDim frameDim   = outFile.addDim("frame");
        NcDim atomDim    = outFile.addDim("atom");
        NcDim spatialDim = outFile.addDim("spatial", 3);
        NcDim radiusDim  = outFile.addDim("radius",1);

        // create the variables
        NcVar coords = outFile.addVar("coordinates", ncFloat, vd({frameDim, atomDim, spatialDim}));
        NcVar radii  = outFile.addVar("radius", ncFloat, vd({frameDim, atomDim}));

        // set up chunking
        vs chunk_coords({1, CHUNK_SIZE, 3});
        vs chunk_radii({1, CHUNK_SIZE, 1});
        coords.setChunking(NcVar::nc_CHUNKED, chunk_coords);
        radii.setChunking(NcVar::nc_CHUNKED, chunk_radii);

        // set up compression
        coords.setCompression(false, true, 1);
        radii.setCompression(false, true, 1);

        return 0;

    }
    catch(NcException& e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The `out.nc` becomes a valid and working `netcdf` file when ...

- ... the CHUNK_SIZE becomes less than 1048577
- ... CHUNKING is disabled
- ... the unused "radius" dimension is named differently or not added at all

Note, that the maximum number of working `CHUNK_SIZE`, `1048576` is the maximal integer number representable by 20 bits.

What causes this behaviour? It is easy to work around by renaming the `radius` dimension, but I am still curious in why this is in any way related to the chunking of HDF5/netcdf.

Comment: What version of the netcdf-c++ library are you using, and do you know what version of the underlying netcdf-c library it is linked against?  While it's still being maintained, the netcdf-c++ library is lagging a bit behind the C and Fortran libraries in terms of being brought up to speed.  There are two versions, the historic 'netcdf-c++ 4.2' release, and the active-moving-forward 'netcdf-c++-4.4' release.

Comment: Hey, I actually did use the 4.2 version to test the behaviour locally, but I also tested it against the latest tarballs from the netcdf website. Both failed. The example I posted above actually was not the failing one, since the dimension was named `radiuss` instead of the conflicting `radius`. I fixed this now. If you copy the example word by word and compile it, it should fail no matter which version of `netcdf` and `netcdf_c++4` you use.

Comment: I must correct myself, I tried only the 4.4 release on both machines. I got confused with the extra 4 after the package name.